# CBL This IP address is HELO'ing as "localhost.localdomain"

Tags: email, email-server, spam, blacklist, smtp

I am pretty lost here, my server somehow got into a blacklist. And I don't know why and how to solve it. Please take a look at the link below.

[CBL List - click here](http://cbl.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi?ip=93.190.139.208&.submit=Lookup)

Anyone knows what is going on here? I am not spamming mails, I am just hosting a forum.

I will provide any information needed, just reply.

Thanks!

EDIT: I have gotten this email.

> This is the mail system at host
>   localhost.localdomain.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that
>   your message could not be delivered to
>   one or more recipients. It's attached
>   below.
>
> For further assistance, please send
>   mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this
>   problem report. You can delete your
>   own text from the attached returned
>   message.
>
> ```
>               The mail system
> ```
>
> <********@atlantmail.com>: host
>   grey-area.mailhostingserver.com[209.62.85.74]
>   said: 550 5.7.1
>   : Helo command
>   rejected: Host not found (in reply to 
>   RCPT TO command)
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822;
>   *******@atlantmail.com Action:
>   failed Status: 5.7.1 Remote-MTA: dns;
>   grey-area.mailhostingserver.com
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.7.1
>   : Helo command 
>   rejected: Host not found

EDIT 2:

My postfix settning:

```
myhostname = yo.atlava.com alias_maps
= hash:/etc/aliases alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases myorigin =
/etc/mailname mydestination =
atlava.com, yo.atlava.com,
localhost.atlava.com, localhost



(none):~# hostname -f
hostname: Unknown host
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the page states, the HELO is not why your server is listed.

*IP Address 93.190.139.208 is listed in the CBL. It appears to be infected with a spam sending trojan or proxy.*

is why your server is listed. You'll need to figure out why it's being flagged as such and correct it.

Changing how your server identifies itself in the HELO is specific to the SMTP server that you're running. Can you give us a clue?

**EDIT**

Ok, got it. You have a couple of problems based on your edit:

1. CBL thinks you're spamming but offers no details on what exactly they're flagging you on.
2. It looks like atlantamail.com is rejecting your email because it can't validate the name your SMTP server is giving in the HELO command. You'll need to figure out where in Postfix to set the outgoing FQDN in the HELO and set it to something legitimate, such as hostname.mypublicdomain.com. If you send and receive email on the same server then it's easiest to set the FQDN to match your MX record and then you can create an SPF record that authorizes your MX to send email for your domain. None of these will guaranteee that your email will be accepted but will help.

Comment: @joeqwerty How do I find my MTA software? I am running a Debian server. And what is a cluse? thanks!

Comment: LOL. Extra "s" there, it should have been clue. What email software (MTA = message transfer agent) are you running on the server?

Comment: @joeqwerty I am using squirrelmail, is that a MTA?

Comment: I don't believe it is. I've edited my question to make it more clear. What SMTP server (this is the MTA that I'm referring to) are you using to send emails from your server/domain?

Comment: @joeqwerty I believe `Postfix` is.

Comment: OK, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: @joeqwerty I followed this `http://www.debianadmin.com/debian-mail-server-setup-with-postfix-dovecot-sasl-squirrel-mail.html` is what you're looking for there? Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @joeqwerty I just edited my postfix settnings.edited my first post.

Comment: I'm not a unix/linux person so I have no idea. I would look at the file referenced in the article in this sentence: Postfix configuration file is located at:/etc/postfix/main.cf. You can edit this file using popular text editor vi /etc/postfix/main.cf.

Comment: @joeqwerty I edited it, posted the parts I edited. hostname -f returns `unknown host` any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with the configuration. I just know that you need to set the outgoing FQDN for the HELO command. Maybe someone with specific experience with Postfix will post the steps for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the document to which you linked, http://cbl.abuseat.org/namingproblems.html was listed as a resource for people in your situation.  Have you followed the steps outlined in that document?  If so, what was the output of the commands (and the contents of the emails) you received as a result?

Comment: I sent a mail to `helocheck\@cbl.abuseat.org` and even `helocheck@cbl.abuseat.org` I did not get any reply back.